# Determining which overrides method is actually invoked

Tags: java

When a subclass object is casted to its superclass, for example

```
Superclass obj = new Subclass();
```

and the classes were defined

```
public class Superclass{
    public void thisMethod(){
        System.out.println("Superclass version was executed");
}
```

and

```
public class Subclass extends Superclass{
    public void thisMethod(){
        System.out.println("Subclass version was called");
}
    public void newMethod(){
        System.out.println("blah");
  }
}
```

When `obj.thisMethod()` was called, I get `Subclass version was called` as the output, which obviously means the version of this method which was defined in the subclass(the version which an original Superclass object cannot "perform") was called, although the declared type is Superclass, yes?
So, if even though the subclass method was executed on obj, 
when `obj.newMethod()` is called, I get a compile error.

Basically, why is the version of `thisMethod()` defined in the subclass being invoked through the Superclass object `obj`? I understand that the actual type of `obj` is still Subclass, so naturally, the new version should get called, but then, shouldn't I be able to call `obj.newMethod()`?

Thanks heaps for any explanations (:

edit: meant overridden* in the title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Basically, why is the version of thisMethod() defined in the subclass being invoked through the Superclass object obj?

Because that's basically the point of inheritance - it allows an implementation to override, without the calling code needing to know which implementation is being used. Take `InputStream` as an example - you can code using `InputStream`, and then the same code will work whether you're passed a `FileInputStream`, a `ByteArrayInputStream` etc. In the case of an abstract class or interface, you may be calling methods which don't *have* any implementation in the compile-time type - but it's guaranteed that there'll be an implementation in the concrete object type being used at execution time.

> I understand that the actual type of obj is still Subclass, so naturally, the new version should get called, but then, shouldn't I be able to call `obj.newMethod()`?

No, because the *compile-time* type of `obj` is `Superclass`. It's really important to differentiate between the *compile-time* type of a variable, which determines which methods etc are available, and the *execution-time* type of the object that the variable's value refers to, which determines which method implementations are actually called.

That's just a very brief description - you should read a good Java book's chapter on inheritance for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In theory `obj` is a `Superclass` reference pointing to a `Subclass` object.

For the compiler `obj` is just a `Superclass` so all `Superclass`'s methods can be called e.g. `thisMethod`, the compiler doesn't know the type of the object, just the type of the reference, because of this the compiler will refuse `newMethod` because it can't prove this method exists.

But at runtime the type of the object is used to dispatch methods not the type of reference, so `thisMethod` will get resolved to `Subclass`'s version.

Now if we know that the runtime object is of type `Subclass` we want to tell the compiler this , we do a cast :

```
Subclass subobj = (Subclass) obj;
```

After that the compiler knows that `subobj` is of type `Subclass` and will accept calling `newMethod`, the cast is just an info for the compiler and doesn't change anything in the object `obj`, had `obj` been not a `Subclass` the previous statement will throw `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Superclass obj = new Subclass() in this definition you can only the exposed method in Superclass.And in your declaration actually pointing to Subclass object when you will call any method it will call subclass implementation